# Extraer datos de un formulario c#

Tags: c#

Necesito extraer 2 campos de una lista, primero lo que hago es el registro de clientes que se van guardando en una lista pero necesito extaer solo 2 campos de la lista que son nombres y apellidos del cliente y que se me muestre en un combobox

```
    private void nombresapellidos()
    {
        comboBox_Cliente.DataSource = manejarCliente.getListaClientes();
        comboBox_Cliente.DisplayMember = "Nombres";
        comboBox_Cliente.DisplayMember = "Apellidos";
    
    
    }
este es el pedazo de codigo en donde por cada vez que se agrega el\nombre del cliente a la lista me devuelve el nombre tambien en el combobox el detalle es que con la funcion displaymenber solo me devuelve el nombre de la lista pero quisiera de alguna manera me devuelva el nombre junto con el apellido concatenado en el combobox. 
Esta es la clase que controla la lista

    private List<Cliente> lista_clientes;
    private static Cliente_Controller instance;
    //Creo una lista vacia
    public Cliente_Controller()
    {
        lista_clientes = new List<Cliente>();
    }     
    //Agrego datos a la lista
    public void AgregarCliente(Cliente obj_cliente)
    {
        lista_clientes.Add(obj_cliente);
    }
    //Retorna la lista
    public List<Cliente> getListaClientes()
    {
        return lista_clientes;
    }
    public static Cliente_Controller Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Cliente_Controller();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No entiendo para nada tu problema... no, no podes mostrar dos campos distintos de una lista como display member.. como dice la documentacion, es el campo a mostrar, no "los campos" a mostrar.. si queres mostrar la conjuncion de los mismos, podrias modificar la clase y agregar una propiedad readonly que muestre la conjuncion de los mismos...

Comment: hay alguna necesidad particular para que esa clase sea un singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu clase cliente creas una propiedad que digamos se llamará `NombreCompleto` donde te retorne el `nombre+apellido`, algo así:

```
public class Cliente{
  public string Nombres { get; set; }
  public string Apellidos{ get; set; }
  public string NombreCompleto => Nombres + " " + Apellidos;

  //El resto de propiedades y métodos
}
```

Y luego en el DisplayMember:

```
comboBox_Cliente.DisplayMember = "NombreCompleto";
```

Comment: lo hare porque dentro del combo box era que necesitaba extraer las 2 propiedades que son el nombre y el apellido del cliente y guardar en un solo dato y que se refleje en el combobox. Gracias por la ayuda